# Calculate an expression given constraints

Tags: equation-solving

How can I solve the following problem using *Mathematica*?

If $a+b+c=0$ and $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 = 0$, calculate $a\,b+b\,c+c\,a$.

Comment: This appears to be a question about math and not Mathematica per se.

Comment: Also, the now-standard way to "reduce" polynomial expressions modulo some others is via Groebner bases and normal form reduction. In Mathematica this is done as `In[133]:= 
PolynomialReduce[a*b + b*c + c*a, 
  GroebnerBasis[{a + b + c, a^2 + b^2 + c^2}, {a, b, c}], {a, b, 
   c}][[2]]

Out[133]= 0`. One could get fancy in terms of term orders but that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use exclusively *Mathematica*, I would solve the two equations for $a$, $b$ and $c$, which would leave one of the variables free, then substitute the solutions in the expression $ab+bc+ca$:

```
(a*b + b*c + c*a) /. 
  Solve[{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 0, a + b + c == 0}, {a, b, c}] // Simplify
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the constraints as `Assumptions` in `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`

```
Simplify[a b + b c + c a, {a + b + c == 0, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 0}]

(*  0  *)
```

Answer (score -1):

(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ac+2ab+2bc
a+b+c=0 so the left side is: (a+b+c)^2=0
a^2+b^2+c^2=0 so the right side is: 0+2ac+2ab+2bc
both sides of this equation will be:
0=2ac+2ab+2bc ==>  0=2(ac+ab+bc)  ==> ac+ab+bc=0/2=0